# Error when loading datatable with VARCHAR(MAX) column

Tags: sql-server, powershell, odbc

I have the Powershell following function to load data from a database via ODBC, given a connection string and a query.

```
function Run-OdbcSQL {
[OutputType([System.Data.DataTable])]
[cmdletbinding()]
param (

        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$ConnString,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$Query
)
    
    $Conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    $Conn.ConnectionString = $ConnString
    $Conn.Open()
    try {
        $Result =(New-Object Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($Query,$Conn)).ExecuteReader()
        
        $Table = New-Object "System.Data.DataTable"
        $Table.Load($Result)
        # Prevent PS from unravelling a table with a single row
        Write-Output -NoEnumerate $Table

    } finally {
        $Conn.Close()
    }
}
```

This works fine, except when one of the columns being returned, is defined as `VARCHAR(MAX)`. In this case, the function returns the error:

```
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to enable constraints. 
One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints."
```

If I modify the query to `SELECT CAST(column_name AS VARCHAR(255)) FROM …`, the data will be loaded without any issue.

Environment:

- Database: SQL Server 2019
- ODBC driver: SQL Server Native Client 11.0 / ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server (reproducible with both)

The issue seems to be a combination of `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `System.Data.DataTable`, but I can't figure how to resolve it.

Comment: It seems there is an issue with the inferred data table schema. Add example `CREATE TABLE` DDL to your question, including constraints. Do you have any additional details in the exception/innerexception?

Comment: SQL Server Native Client is deprecated and should not be used in any new development work. It hasn't been updated since SQL Server 2012. Although it has data type compatability modes for working with the `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` data types that is not readily available through the ODBC connector. Try instead using the ADO.NET capabilities via the [`System.Data.SqlClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient) namespace.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning you're correct regarding SQL Native Client. I tested the code again with ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server, and the issue still persists (with same workaround).

Answer (score 0):

No definite solution, but I have managed to find some workarounds.

The `CAST(<columnname> AS VARCHAR(<length>)` works, but you're limited to 8000 characters because "*`SQL_CHAR` and `SQL_VARCHAR` data types are limited to a maximum length of 8,000 characters*" [[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)][[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-results/data-type-usage?view=sql-server-ver15)]

The `text` datatype on the other hand, can hold 2^30 - 1 bytes (identical to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`) and it seems to be passed through correctly (couldn't find any concrete info). Thus: `CAST( AS TEXT) avoids the issue.

### Test case

- *Data*: given a `query` column defined as `VARCHAR(MAX)`, retrieving a single row where the contents of the column are 100.000 characters long.
- *Middleware*: Tests were executed using both *ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server* and *SQL Server Native Client 11.0*. Results were identical for either driver.
- *Database*: Microsoft SQL Server 2019.

| Query | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `SELECT query` | `Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints."` |
| `SELECT CAST(query as VARCHAR(8000))` | OK, truncated at 8.000 characters |
| `SELECT CAST(query as VARCHAR(10000))` | `The size (10000) given to the type 'varchar' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000).` |
| `SELECT CAST(query as TEXT)` | OK, 10.000 characters |

### Remarks

For other databases (using different middleware), this approach might not work. E.g. for PostgreSQL, you need to use the `MaxLongVarcharSize` property, which is set to `8190` by default, and supports up to `65535` bytes.